# Efeito número aumentando/diminuindo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Procurei no **SOpt** e não encontrei **o que desejava**
Suponhamos que eu tenha um **botão** e, ao efetuar um **clique**, ele **altere** o valor de alguma ***div*** ou **input**. O valor inicial seja **1**, e ao **clicar**, mude para **10**.

Gostaria que essa **transição** não fosse **direta**. Gostaria que os números fossem **crescendo**, do **1** ao **10** (**Ex:** *1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 e, finalmente 10*).
Pensei em fazer com **setTnterval e um loop**, mas não consegui pensar na solução em si.

*Tenho preferência por jQuery.*

Deixarei um trecho para ajudar. Desde já, obrigado pela atenção.

```js
$("#alterarValor").click(function(){
$("#numero").text("10");
});
$("#voltarValor").click(function(){
$("#numero").text("1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numero">1</div>
<input type="button" id="alterarValor" value="Alterar valor" />
<input type="button" id="voltarValor" value="Resetar" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens de criar um loop com  `setTimeout` que vai mudando. Com um loop começas os `setTimout` todos ao mesmo tempo mas usando o `i` para multiplicar o tempo de espera o efeito é o que procuras.

Exemplo com 5 segundos de transição:

```js
$("#alterarValor").click(function() {
  var numero = document.getElementById('numero');
  var min = 1;
  var max = 20;
  var duração = 5000; // 5 segundos

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(nr) {
      numero.innerHTML = nr;
    }, i * 5000 / max, i);
  }
});

$("#voltarValor").click(function() {
  $("#numero").text("1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numero">1</div>
<input type="button" id="alterarValor" value="Alterar valor" />
<input type="button" id="voltarValor" value="Resetar" />
```

Comment: Perfeito. Exatamente o que eu desejava. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a pergunta já foi respondida, mas, de qualquer forma, segue exemplo de outra maneira de fazer isso com os números em ordem crescente e decrescente para aumentar a base de conhecimento:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("#alterarValorCrescente").click(function(){
    //Valor inicial
    var count = 1;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
      $('#contagem').html(count);
      //Valor final
      if (count >= 10){
        //Ao chegar no valor final (10) interrompe a contagem
        clearInterval(countdown);
      }
      count++;
      //Transição a cada meio segundo
    }, 500);
  });
  $("#alterarValorDecrescente").click(function(){
    //Valor inicial
    var count = 10;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
      $('#contagem').html(count);
      //Valor final
      if (count == 1){
        //Ao chegar no valor final (1) interrompe a contagem
        clearInterval(countdown);
      }
      count--;
      //Transição a cada meio segundo
    }, 500);
  });
  $("#voltarValor").click(function(){
    $("#contagem").text("1");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contagem">1</div>
<button id="alterarValorCrescente">Alterar valor +</button>
<button id="alterarValorDecrescente">Alterar valor -</button>
<button id="voltarValor">Resetar</button>
```

Comment: Opa! Muito obrigado amigo! Estarei analisando!

Comment: Desculpe só responder agora. Mas eu testei seu script e achei ele ainda mais interessante que o outro. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Leandro como fazer para que isso ocorra no load da pagina, sem precisar clicar no botão "alterar valor"?